# why the last tick doesn't have values - D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The last ticks in x-axis and y-axis don't have values drawn next to them. I cannot figure out why these values are missing.

This is the JS code :

```
var xAxisScale = d3.scale.linear()
         .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.x; })])
       .range([padding, containerWidth - padding * 2]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xAxisScale).orient("bottom");

    var xGuide = chartContainer.append('g')
      .attr("class", "xAxis")
      .call(xAxis)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0 ,' + (containerHeight -padding) + ')');


    /* Code for adding y axis in chart
     * 
     * */
    var yAxisScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d.y})])
      .range([containerHeight-padding, padding ]);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yAxisScale).orient("left");

    var yGuide = chartContainer.append('g')
      .attr("class", "yAxis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .attr('transform', 'translate('+padding + ',0)');
```

This is my [live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9CZlu9UmacaLjwAlsz2e?p=preview).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by overriding the default behavior for determining tick values using [`axis.tickValues()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickValues):

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yAxisScale).orient("left")
  .tickValues(yAxisScale.ticks().concat(yAxisScale.domain()));
```

This still resorts to the automatically generated tick values by calling `yAxisScale.ticks()` which is the default behavior for D3's axes. These values are then supplemented with the outer bounds of your data values, i.e. the array returned by `yAxisScale.ticks()`. To set just the upper bound, if would be sufficient to specify `yAxisScale.domain()[1]`, although it won't hurt having duplicate values in the array provided to `.tickValues()`.

Doing it this way frees you from any hardcoding of tick values.

Have a look at this working example:

```js
var padding = 70;

     //Width and height
     var containerWidth = 1000;
     var containerHeight = 500;
     var data = [{
       "x": 82,
       "y": 1730
     }, {
       "x": 533,
       "y": 16385
     }, {
       "x": 41,
       "y": 783
     }, {
       "x": 20.5,
       "y": 5873
     }, {
       "x": 553.5,
       "y": 25200
     }, {
       "x": 61.5,
       "y": 30000
     }, {
       "x": 184.5,
       "y": 2853
     }, {
       "x": 1476,
       "y": 83775
     }];
     //Create scale functions
   var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    
         
     var chartContainer = d3.select("body")
       .append("svg")
       .attr("class", "chartContainer")
       .attr("width", containerWidth)
       .attr("height", containerHeight);

     $(".chartContainer").css({
       "background-color": "",
       "position": "absolute",
       "top": 50,
       "left": 15
     });
      
         
     var xAxisScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.x; })])
        .range([padding, containerWidth - padding * 2]);

     var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xAxisScale).orient("bottom")
       .tickValues(xAxisScale.ticks().concat(xAxisScale.domain()));
 
     var xGuide = chartContainer.append('g')
       .attr("class", "xAxis")
       .call(xAxis)
       .attr('transform', 'translate(0 ,' + (containerHeight -padding) + ')');

xGuide.selectAll('path')
     .style({ fill: 'none', stroke: "#000"});
    xGuide.selectAll('line')
     .style({ stroke: "#000"});
     /* Code for adding y axis in chart
      * 
      * */
     var yAxisScale = d3.scale.linear()
       .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d.y})])
       .range([containerHeight-padding, padding ]);

     var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yAxisScale).orient("left")
       .tickValues(yAxisScale.ticks().concat(yAxisScale.domain()[1]));

     var yGuide = chartContainer.append('g')
       .attr("class", "yAxis")
       .call(yAxis)
       .attr('transform', 'translate('+padding + ',0)');

     chartContainer.selectAll("circle")
       .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("cx", function(d) {
         return xAxisScale(d.x);
       })
       .attr("cy", function(d) {
         return yAxisScale(d.y);
       })
       .attr("r", 4)
       .attr("fill", "red")
       .attr({
         "z-index": "9999"
       });
       
       yGuide.selectAll('path')
     .style({ fill: 'none', stroke: "#000"});
    yGuide.selectAll('line')
     .style({ stroke: "#000"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `.nice()` to line 69 of your [live demo.](http://plnkr.co/edit/9CZlu9UmacaLjwAlsz2e?p=preview) will solve the issue. See graph below for the end result.

For more details and explanation, please refer to [this](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/issues/86) closed issue on the d3-scale library. mbostock commented on it on Dec 6, 2016 and provided the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using d3's automatic tick generator which makes a best guess on how best to draw your axes given the data in the chart.

You have two options for overriding this:

1. Setting a number of tick values to show. For example:

   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                 .scale(xAxisScale)
                 .orient("bottom")
                 .ticks(10);
2. Passing a tick values array to explicitly tell d3 what values you want on your x or y axis; like this:

   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                 .scale(xAxisScale)
                 .orient("bottom")
                 .tickValues([0, 100, 200, 300, 400]);

If you want to get rid of the ticks that are missing values (in your case, the outer ticks) just set .outerTickSize(0) on the x or y-axis.

You should also probably read up on the d3's axes API [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes).