# D3 Bar Chart Values Out of Scale Range

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I have a barchart here that is pretty good:
https://jsfiddle.net/r6jkht9v/1/

One thing that I would like to change is to give myself a little extra space for the `July` data.
I feel like just by looking at the chart you don't know how much more there is over 50k, the chart ends.

Ideally I like the scale/range to go a little above the highest value. I've tried a few things, adding a value here or there to the yscale but it always makes it worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pad your y scale by changing this:

```
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, maxRevenue])
  .range([height, 0])
```

To this:

```
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, parseInt(maxRevenue) + 5000])
  .range([height, 0])
```

Comment: This also helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314835/why-the-last-tick-doesnt-have-values-d3-js